# SCTP on node.js

Tags: node.js, sctp

Is there an implementation of the SCTP (Stream Control Transmission Protocol) , also called the VOIP protocol on Node.js? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: SCTP != VoIP.  SCTP is a protocol - a peer of TCP and UDP.  Vock is just VoIP, no mention of SCTP in the READMEs.

Answer (score 2):

Per vock source

```
  this.socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
```

I don't think it is using SCTP.

** UPDATE**

As a followup - I did find this project https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc that does support SCTP currently.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sctp

Though, as of now, it comes with a warning:

> Warning! Warning! Warning!
>
> Implementation of RFC4960 is currently incomplete and unstable, don't
>   use in production environment!